# how to get a list of entities without a particular attribute in EF 5?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am building an MVC 4 app. I have view that has a dropdown that needs to display specific tables (entities) used..

Some entities have an attribute called DoNotAUdit

```
[DoNotAudit]
    public class AuditLog
    {
        public Guid AuditLogId { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set;}
        public DateTime EventDateUTC { get; set; }
        public string EventType { get; set; }
        public string TableName { get; set; }
        public string RecordId { get; set; }
        public string ColumnName { get; set; }
        public string OriginalValue { get; set; }
        public string NewValue { get; set; }

    }
```

While other entities do not have that custom attribute.

I just want to get a list of all entities that do not have that attribute.

Another stack overflow user Radenko Zec showed me how to get all tables (as that was what I asked him) but now I need a bit more help

To get all tables he suggested the following,

```
using System.Data.Metadata.Edm;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

...

using (dbcontext context = new TestContext())
{
   ObjectContext objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
   MetadataWorkspace workspace = objContext.MetadataWorkspace;
   IEnumerable<EntityType> tables = workspace.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.SSpace);

}
```

How can I do that? I am using EF 5 code first with configurations.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: would you like to get a list of entity TYPES? which have no this attribute?

Comment: You'll most likely have to attack this one using reflection instead of EF.

Comment: potehin143 - yes I want to get a list of entities that do not have this attribute.

Comment: Keith Payne - any sample code?

Comment: potehin143 - I only need the entity name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 try this     

 typeof(TestContext).GetProperties().Select(n => n.PropertyType) // here we get all properties of contect class
.Where(n => n.Name.Contais("DbSet") && n.IsGenericType) // here we select only DBSet collections
.Select(n=>n.GetGenericArgumenrs()[0])//Here we access to TEntiy type in DbSet<TEntity> 
.Where(n => n.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<DoNotAudit>().FirstOrDefault()== null) // here we check for attribute existence
 .OrderBy(n=>n.Name) // Here is sorting by Name
.Select(n => n.Name).ToList(); // here we select the names of entity classes
```